# How can I add a new item to a multiselect list by pressing tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I've added autocomplete so it chooses the items that are in the options, but new items, even though I've allowed them.

If I type an item that isn't in the list, the user has to press up arrow and then tab for it to work.

Is there any way to just press enter.

It appears related to this item too:
[Configurable "Complete Hint" Key Configuration](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/330)

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this in a HOC to get to the selections.  I tried passing in a keyDownEvent from my event handler, but couldn't work out how to manipulate the selection in the state.

EDIT: 
Code from the repo demo pages

```
class CustomSelectionsExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Typeahead
        allowNew
        multiple
        newSelectionPrefix="Add a new item: "
        options={[]}
        placeholder="Type anything..."
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#custom-selections demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to select via tab, enter, or either?